# Inserting timestamp in oracle timestamp column

Tags: oracle, timestamp

I have a table in which there is a column with datatype `TIMESTAMP(0)`

When I insert a date into this column using

```
INSERT INTO TEST_TIMESTAMP VALUES(SYSDATE)
```

it inserts a date in the following example format

`12-SEP-12 10.31.19.000000000 AM`

I want to know how the below timestamp formats can be inserted in the table

`12-SEP-12 10.31.19` and `12-SEP-12 10.31.19 AM`

I tried specifying some formats using `TO_CHAR` while inserting `SYSDATE` into the table, but it didn't work.

Please suggest.

Comment: A `timestamp` or `date` datatype doesn't have a format. A format is only needed when you retrieve the value to display it to a user.

Comment: `TIMESTAMP(0)` is effectively the same as `DATE`, which will store times down to the second anyway. Your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting may not make that obvious as it could only show the date part by default, but `TO_CHAR(<date_field>, 'DD-Mon-RR HH24.MI.SS')` would include the time. (The data types are explained in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/sql_elements001.htm#sthref148))

Answer (score 3):

when you store a `TIMESTAMP` it will always store the data at maximum precision (with fractional seconds).

I think what you want to do is supply a format to display the date when you retrieve it from the database.

You can do this like so:

```
select to_char(timestampColumnName,'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS') "Date" from test_timestamp
```

or

```
select to_char(timestampColumnName,'DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS AM') "Date" from test_timestamp
```

Comment: @paul- i know how to retrieve the timestamp in different formats. Only concern is how can i insert it in the specified format as mentioned above in the problem?

Comment: are you wanting to use something like `TO_TIMESTAMP('12-SEP-12 10.31.19','DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS')`?

Answer (score 1):

You can return it very easy like:

> SELECT to_char(sysdate,'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL;
>
> > In your case use:
> >
> > > INSERT INTO TEST_TIMESTAMP(column_name) VALUES(to_char(sysdate,'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'));

Answer (score 0):

You were missing the extra ().

```
INSERT INTO TEST_TIMESTAMP
VALUES (TO_TIMESTAMP('12-SEP-12 10.31.19', 'DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS'));

INSERT INTO TEST_TIMESTAMP
VALUES (TO_TIMESTAMP('12-SEP-12 10.31.19 AM', 'DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS AM'));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

This for colum type insert over mode `to_char`.